# How to get the audio and video from a WebRTC stream using ffmpeg on server

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, sdp

I am trying to get the audio and video from a WebRTC stream and handle it (transcode or dump) with ffmpeg on ubuntu server. I have naively expected it to simply interpret the sdp offered by WebRTC, but was mistaken. I suspect ffmpeg is not capable of signaling back the answer sdp and it is must be done manually. Here is an offer sdp:

```
v=0
o=Mozilla-SIPUA-33.1 3662 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=SIP Call
t=0 0
a=ice-ufrag:5e0a74d1
a=ice-pwd:7446c0eb445117d0018ca2afc5f3ca54
a=fingerprint:sha-256 76:1B:19:CE:3F:41:C5:4D:64:E6:FD:72:D2:FC:42:E1:98:D4:0F:2B:73:AE:C7:F4:2C:73:2C:E7:9E:DC:6A:EB
m=audio 23063 RTP/SAVPF 109 0 8 101
c=IN IP4 188.253.146.208
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=ptime:20
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=setup:actpass
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.100 4130 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 188.253.146.208 23063 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 4130
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.100 4131 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 188.253.146.208 23064 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 4131
a=rtcp-mux
m=video 23065 RTP/SAVPF 120 126 97
c=IN IP4 188.253.146.208
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01f
a=sendrecv
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack
a=rtcp-fb:126 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:126 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack
a=rtcp-fb:97 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:97 ccm fir
a=setup:actpass
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2128609535 192.168.1.100 4132 typ host
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 1692467199 188.253.146.208 23065 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 4132
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2128609534 192.168.1.100 4133 typ host
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 1692467198 188.253.146.208 23066 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 4133
a=rtcp-mux
```

Is anybody have succeeded in it? Thanks.

Comment: You will need some sort of gateway to handle the webrtc set up as there are many more steps besides exchanging SDPs.

Comment: I understand. What ever it takes, I am ready to type ffmpeg CLI parameters, and then put up an offer manually. I just need to proof the concept of ffmpeg receiving WebRTC stream.

Comment: The only way I would know how would be to use a gateway to do all the dialog and then piping off the rtp to be sent to a UDP port that your FFMpeg command will then listen to. I have done this successfully with [Janus-gateway](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway) and gstreamer's libav elements. So, using FFMPeg would be a similar process and should work.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible without "something" in between the stream source (peer) and ffmpeg; until and unless ffmpeg starts working with DTLS and you know the hash information for the peer (obviously this could be in the SDP). So in summary, ffmpeg would need DTLS and ICE support. An alternative would be to use GStreamer with plugins.