# Stream video from a stand alone desktop application(not browser) to a remote desktop application(not browser)

Tags: webrtc, rtsp, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm trying to build a live video streaming application from a usb camera to an application running on a remote desktop. I've researched protocols like RTMP, RTSP, WebRTC. According to my understanding I can't use webRTC since it's only compatible in the browser and I'm not building my application for a browser here. Please help me choose the right protocol and also the media server.

Comment: 'Right Protocol' is pretty subjective, I don't think you will get a single good answer. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D39st5UmGh0 is a good video that talks about all the options possible. If you are doing P2P you probably don't want the added complexity of a media server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and many applications do, use WebRTC outside the browser. WebRTC implementations are available for many different platforms including iOS, Android and embedded systems.

You can even use [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) if you want to use the Chrome APIs without the visual parts of the browser.

Comment: Might be nice to list out the options for 'WebRTC outside the browser'! I think is the right answer and should be accepted, but just might be nice to give a little more direction. Not an exhaustive list, but I sorta started one here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906617/5472819